# Is it OK to have one of my letters of recommendation written by a Postdoc?

Tags: phd, mathematics, application, recommendation-letter

I am a Master's student in Mathematics who is planning to apply to a PhD program.

During my research I have been closely working with a Postdoc of my advisor, who is now leaving for another Postdoc position in Europe, and it is not likely he will have a permanent position by the time I need to send the recommendation letters.

Would having him write one of 3 letters of recommendation put me at a significant disadvantage comparing to a case where the author of said letter is a tenured professor who is however less familiar with my research abilities (e.g someone I have taken a course with, or someone who has read my thesis/papers but haven't had significant interaction with me in person)?

Comment: Who write the other two?